# Error dropping database in MySQL 5.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: directory, mysql, database

I am using **MySQL v5.1** on **Ubuntu** machine.

I have a database named my_db which I would like to drop it, so I execute command:

```
mysql> drop database my_db;

ERROR 1010 (HY000): Error dropping database (can't rmdir './my_db/', errno: 17)
```

As you see above, there is an error....Why I can not drop database?

**P.S.** I know all the database related files are located on `/var/lib/mysql/my_db/`

Comment: From your previous posts, I'd say you've messed up something under `/var/lib/mysql`. If you're learning, fine. If this is in production, back up `/var/lib/mysql`, recreate your databases using `mysql` commands only (never manipulating files) and import the data as best as you can.

Answer (score 3):

A quick test program shows `errno = 17` is "File exists" (just an observation, not that I'd expect you to figure it out before posting).

I found [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,93443,93567#msg-93567) on the mysql site, which suggests that you have files in `/var/lib/mysql/my_db/` that mysql didn't create (or that it thinks it didn't create).  List the files (you'll need to `sudo`) and see what's there.  Try moving anything there to a temporary directory (or deleting if you're really sure you won't need them), then try again.

Comment: Definitely mv them, not delete. It'd would suck if mysql starts to error out because it can't find the files it wants to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner and permissions on `/var/lib/mysql/my_db` my immediate thought is that the user account running the mysql daemon does not have the proper permissions to remove the folder.

You could kill `mysqld` and start it as root then try removing the database to test.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you have to check the following:

1. Check in the directory to see that there aren't any unnecessary files that aren't related to your database. Because the `DROP database` removes just database files then the directory, and since you probably have other files there that aren't related to the database files it doesn't remove them and hence it cannot remove the directory.
2. If that doesn't work try to remove the database with `PHPMYADMIN`, mostly it works with it.

Check these out:

- [From StackOverflow site, same problem same error code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17)
- [Blog post without your same error code but with same problem](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-database-errno-39/801)